# Jupyter kernel crash after installing anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter, conda

My Jupyter kernel always crashes after installing anaconda.

Without anaconda, jupyter notebook works fine.
After installation of conda,

```
No module named ipykernel_launcher
```

is the terminal error, and kernel keeps restarting.
I tried looking at some other solutions, but they were not helpful.

Comment: Did you resolve this question?

Comment: I had to reinstall

Comment: I also reinstalled it. Maybe you could write your solution as an answer and accept it, for the future visitors?